# Horizontal scrollbar on profile page questions list in Chrome

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

A minor UI glitch: The profile page of any user shows a scroll bar.

[image: horizontal scrollbar in questions list]

Comment: @badp I'm pretty sure this is a different bug than the linked duplicate. I was under the impression the previous one was fixed, while this isn't. In addition, this also occurs for me with Firefox 3.6.15 on Windows 7.

Comment: @Oak The fix for the previous bug induced this bug. It's reported thrice on that answer, and a new fix is assumedly on the way.

Comment: @Grace ok now I see it, haven't noticed the comments before.